# Convex Optimization related problem

Tags: convex-polytopes, convexity, convex-optimization, convex-analysis

Suppose two non-negative convex functions  $f$ and $g$ be given. 
We want to solve the following optimization
$$\max_{g\leq\epsilon}f.$$

Now suppose that both $f$ and $g$ can be upper-bounded by a convex combination of finite number of functions $\{f_i\}$, and $\{g_i\}$ i.e., $$f\leq \sum_{i}\alpha_i f_i,$$ and 
$$g\leq\sum_{i}\alpha_i g_i,$$

Can we show that 
$$\max_{g\leq \epsilon}f\leq \sum_i\alpha_i\max_{g_i\leq \epsilon_i}f_i$$ where $\sum_{i}\alpha_i\epsilon_i=\epsilon$?

If not, is there any established relations between these two?

Comment: What if $g(x)=0$ for all $x$, $g_1(x)=g_2(x)=10$ for all $x$, and $\epsilon=0$. There may not be any values $x$ for which $g_i(x) \leq \epsilon_i$.